# Can I use a listener style filter with an "if" statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, firefox-addon-webextensions, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm try to take a chrome/firefox extension and run it on Edge.

The chrome extension creates a listener when a url is called.

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onBeforeRequest, {'urls': urls, 'types': ['main_frame']}, ['blocking', 'requestBody']);
```

The extension creates over 1000 of these listeners for different urls and in chrome it works fine.  In Edge I think I'm overflowing the heap.

Is there a way I can create 1 listener for all URLs and then in the function call a for loop to go through the url filters and see if the current url matches?

for example this is what I tried.

```
    for (var f_key in resourceRecords) {

      var matchedURL = false;
      var jLength = resourceFunctions[f_key]['urls'].length;
        for (var j = 0; j < jLength; j++) { 
          if (resourceFunctions[f_key]['urls'][j].matches(details['url'])) {
            matchedURL = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!matchedURL) {
          continue;
        }

     //Code from the chrome extension
   }
```

Thank you.  You guys are great.

Comment: It's more efficient to use a hashtable for the lookup, but otherwise the code should work, it's quite trivial. Or is there a problem? Do your `urls` use regexp or wildcard patterns?

Comment: Yes wildcard patterns.  For example `*://bkinformation.com/*` is used for the url `http://bkinformation.com/`

Comment: You'll need to replace `*` with `.*?` and escape other special characters like `.` with `\.` See [an example](//stackoverflow.com/a/39037930)